# bootstrap buttons onclick events

Tags: javascript, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 bootstrap buttons, I is a direct link to another page on the website and the other one I want to activate a javascript onclick event. I have no problem with a basic link but when adding it to a button it doesnt seem to work? I have included the code I am using with the link thats works but the button doesnt.

The code is :

```
<div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
<!-- Button -->
<div class="col-sm-12 controls">
Are you already registered?
<a href='login' button type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-success'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</button></a>
<div class="spacing3"></div>Not yet?

<button id='next' name ='next' type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-primary'>Continue</button>
</div>
</div>

<a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#1box').show()">Login here</a>
```

And the js for the button is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn-next').on('click', function() {
$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#1box').show();
}
```

Comment: you don't have any id="btn-next" in your html

Comment: your button id is `#next` not `#btn-next`

Comment: @Jules - Please see my answer and accept it as answer if its hellpful..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this

```
<button id='next' name ='next' type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-primary'>Continue</button>
```

to

```
<button id='btn-next' name ='next' type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-primary'>Continue</button>
```

as you are applying event on btn-next ID `$('#btn-next').on('click'`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#next').on('click', function() {
      $('#loginbox').hide(); 
      $('#1box').show();
   })
});
```

Acyually u r using wrong id.

```
$('#btn-next')
```

should be

```
$('#next')
```

Another solution could be, change your id from html like:

```
<button id='btn-next' name ='next' type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-primary'>Continue</button>
```

And then jquery as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-next').on('click', function() {
      $('#loginbox').hide(); 
      $('#1box').show();
   })
});
```

Comment: Sorry that doesnt work! Even when i add btn-next to text?

Comment: Please update your html and let me see whats the problem

Comment: Please note that its a click event. The code will be fired when user will click that button.